# Can an @Relation be queried in Android Room

Tags: android, android-room

I didn't really expect this to work, but can Android Room @Relation be filtered with a `WHERE` clause.  For example:

`SELECT * FROM meta  WHERE subjectId IN (?)`

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [ MetadataEntity::class, SubjectJunction::class ])
internal abstract fun internalGetImages(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): LiveData<List<MetadataXmp>>
```

`

```
data class MetadataXmp @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @Embedded
    val metadata:MetadataEntity,
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "metaId",
            projection = ["subjectId"],
            entity = SubjectJunction::class)
    var subjectIds: List<Long> = Collections.emptyList())
```

This throws `no such column: subjectId`.  I suspect that `@Relation` is only gathered based on the core query result and the relational columns are never present for the initial query, but I wanted to see if the relation could referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but you can query the @Relation. You can find an example [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1) (see tip 6).

Comment: Not quite the same thing.  That's a query with a join at the end.  This Q was hoping that a query could select based on a relation.  Thise feature request was different as well, but as it just got picked up, there's potential that they're working on 1:N and M:N queries.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69201917